# Self hosted and ping problems on local network

Tags: server, localhost

The problem is i have an self hosted server (Obico its an thing for 3d printing) and i can use my local ip on the host PC so it reach correctly the page but from another PC or device i cant reach the page (i disabled AV and firewall for testings). I can still ping form host to client but not client to host.

Any solutions ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you use 127.0.0.1 on the host PC?  On another PC on the same network you'll need to use 192.168.x.y.  Type `ipconfig` from a command prompt to find out the exact IP for the local network.

Comment: What OS versions and IPs do the involved devices have? How are they connected? What does `tracert.exe $clientIP` say when ran on the host? What is the URL you want to reach from the browser? Once network problems appear there's just so much that can be the cause so we need further info to find the right one.